# Chaincode path does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Problem:**

I have set up a Hyperledger Fabric network. When I try to install a chaincode it is only installed in the first peer. But when I try to install chaincode on other peers it was failed by saying that chaincode does not exist.

This is the command I issued on the first peer.

```
peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/fabcar/javascript-low-level
```

This is the output after the command.

> 2020-03-01 07:27:26.245 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
>   2020-03-01 07:27:26.245 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
>   2020-03-01 07:27:26.705 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 003 Installed remotely response:

This is the command I issued on the second peer.

```
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.hrm.com/users/Admin@doctor.hrm.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.doctor.hrm.com:10051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="DoctorMSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/doctor.hrm.com/peers/peer1.doctor.hrm.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/fabcar/javascript-low-level
```

This is the error that was given to me.

> 2020-03-01 07:34:28.268 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
>   2020-03-01 07:34:28.268 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
>   Error: error getting chaincode code fabcar: path to chaincode does not exist: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/fabcar/javascript-low-level

Can someone help me with this to find the issue?

Comment: @AdityaArora you need docker-compose-cli.yaml file

Comment: Please share the docker-compose-cli.yam file

Comment: Where are you running the command?

Answer (score 0):

Check your GOPATH set in cli container docker-compose.yaml file.

If `GOPATH=/opt/gopath` then you should give path inside src folder. So you should give path in peer chaincode install as `github.com/fabcar/javascript-low-level`

so your command will be

`peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0.0 -l node -p github.com/chaincode/fabcar/javascript-low-level`

so check your GOPATH set in cli container of docker-compose.yaml and accordingly set the path in peer chaincode install command